# Strategy to import many scss files

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack

I'm used in Rails to be able to import many sass or scss files in a single import statement. In my `application.scss` I'd put the following, which would import all files and folders in the folders base/modules/layouts:

```
@import 'base/**/*';
@import 'blocks/**/*';
@import 'layouts/**/*';
```

Is there any way to accomplish this in a Webpack (2.0) and React (15) context?

Comment: You can import your main scss in the index of your app and do all the importa thru sass..

Comment: But can I import **all** files in a folder or would I need to import them one by one?

Comment: Did you try that one https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-glob-loader ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a preloader like this for webpack `https://github.com/Aintaer/import-glob-loader` to achieve the behaviour. Basically this preloader expands your `import` statement before compiling them. Read more on the github page.